# Consume WCF Web Service using Objective-C on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wcf, web-services

I am having a hard time consuming a very simple (Hello World) WCF web service in my iPhone app.  From what I have read, you must manually create the request message then send it to the web service URL.

I was able to accomplish this on a .asmx web service, but not with a WCF service.

How do I know the correct format of the request SOAP message?

The web service I am trying to hit has a format of:
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:PORT/IService1/ (running locally in a VM)

I apologize for the lack of information, I am pretty lost.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: JWD, I'm curious can you detect the service using wcftestclient? Is this a remotely hosted service or are you running it locally?

Comment: I can view and invoke it using wcftestclient, it is running on my macbook inside a windows XP VMWare image, inside of visual studio.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Thank to everyone that helped here. I ended up figuring it out and thought I would share my results.  I know this is not a comprehensive solution, so shoot me a message or comment if you require more detail.

```
//Variables used
NSMutableData *webData;
NSMutableString *soapResults;
NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
BOOL recordResults;

//Web Service Call
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope \n"
"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
"xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n" 
"xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
"SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
"xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"
"<SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
"<Login xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><username>JACKSON</username><password>PASSWORD</password>"
"</Login> \n"
"</SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.0.142:8731/Service1/"];               
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];             
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];          
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/Login" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(theConnection) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}

//Implement the NSURL and XMLParser protocols
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnection methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark XMLParser methods

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to access an svc file in a similar way but dont get a response - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327673/consuming-svc-service-from-iphone-app. Could really use some help! Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
i am trying to consume an svc web method which expects an object having image and some string as parameters....I am bit confused to create the post method for the same....any advise??

Comment: @lostInTransit I am also trying to access the web-service & failed in accessing with desired results.. Can I get any help from you?

Comment: @devaditya Hey bro, I am trying the same as yours. Do you found any solution?

Comment: @hpiOSCoder you might want to post a separate question if you have a specific problem (and the answer does not help)

Comment: @lostInTransit Hey thanks bro for reply. I already posted a question & founded the answer at my own - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910135/svc-webservice-objective-c

Comment: do we need to make any changes in WCF service to access it from iOS app?

Comment: How to pass credential for authenticating with Sharepoint site.

Comment: Worked for me but I need to use Service.svc in URL, "http://172.16.0.142:8731/Service1/Service.svc" and also need to use whatever methods you need to call in Headers message.

Answer (score 10):

Personally i would recommend adding a REST based endpoint for the WCF service.  You can run it simultaneously with the SOAP and its a LOT easier to consume on the iPhone side.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What kind of error are you getting when you hit our WCF service? So asmx is working but not WCF? One thing you need to pay attention is that in .NET 2.0, the web services (asmx) supported both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 messages. However, basicHttpBinding in WCF handles only SOAP 1.1. So if you're sending SOAP 1.2 messages from your iPhone client to the WCF service with basicHttpBinding, this could very well be the problem you're having. In order to support SOAP 1.2, you need to use wsHttpBinding or create a custom binding pretty much the same as basicHttpBinding but you specify the message version to be SOAP 1.2.

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="customHttpBindingWithSoap12">
     <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
     <httpTransport />              
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Caged / httpriot](http://github.com/Caged/httpriot) Simple HTTP Rest Library for iPhone and Cocoa projects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access the WCF service as a Web Service from a windows client?  I haven't configured WCF to run as an asmx styled Web Service but I believe there are some specific settings that have to be tweaked to get WCF to act like in that manner.  Working with a windows client would take out any iphone based issues out of the picture for testing purposes and would help you narrow your testing to the service itself.

Comment: I have not tried a windows client, just the WCF Test Client that runs from Visual Studio.  I believe the service is running correctly, my question is more focused on consuming it with objective C on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are using BasicHttpBinding (not WSHttpBinding) which is aimed more are clients that are not on the .NET 3.0 platform.  This Binding does not support security, reliability or ordered delivery.