# Access sharepoint web services in iphone app

Tags: iphone, sharepoint

I am trying to access sharepoint default web services from my iPhone app. Can some one help me with how to construct the request and get the proper response.

Thanks,
Naresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for answer..

[Consume WCF Web Service using Objective-C on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-in-objective-c-on-an-iphone/1241651#1241651)

Answer (score 1):

Your question can really only be answered in two parts.  Part one is how to construct a request to any web service...which is what the answer at [Consume WCF Web Service using Objective-C on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-in-objective-c-on-an-iphone/1241651#1241651) will show you.

The second part is SharePoint related - their web services requires you to construct chunks of XML that are passed as parameters, and the XML you pass in is in a format that Microsoft specifies. For example, Lists.UpdateList method (at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelist ) requires 6 parameters, 4 of which are XML fragments -- which will need to be encoded and escaped.  (SharePoint's web services are difficult to deal with on any platform and I would expect it to be doubly so from iPhone).