# Trying to connect Android App to .NET ".svc" webservice and server responds Media type not supported

Tags: .net, android, web-services

I am trying to connect Android App to Axapta web-service which is having .svc extension.
I am using Ksoap 2.5.4 jar with all dependencies. Following is the code.
I could not connect to web-service because response dump indicates that media type not supported by server.

---

Web Service :

Up and running properly while connecting from Windows Phone

---

Code :

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SoapActivity extends Activity {
     private static String mSOAPACTION="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/LocalEndpointService/read",
                           mOPERATIONNAME="read",
                           WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/";

     private static String mNAMESPACE="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/";
     private static String mMETHODNAME="read";
     private static String mURL="http://192.168.100.188/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/localendpointservice.svc?wsdl";
     private SoapPrimitive result = null;
     public static Context context=null;
     private HttpTransportSE  httpTransportSE = null;
     private TextView tv = null;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = null;
     SoapObject Request = null;
     ServiceConnection sc = null;
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
     try {
         envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
         envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
         envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
         envelope.env=SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENV;
         envelope.implicitTypes = true;
         Request = new SoapObject(mNAMESPACE, mMETHODNAME);
         //Request = new SoapObject(mNAMESPACE, mOPERATIONNAME);         
         //Request.addProperty("LocalEndpointServiceReadRequest", "Qing");       
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);      
         //envelope.addMapping(mNAMESPACE, "UserCredentials",new UserCredendtials().getClass());
         /*androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(mURL);
         androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
         androidHttpTransport.call(mSOAPACTION, envelope);*/

         httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(mURL);
         /*sc = httpTransportSE.getConnection();
         if(sc!=null){
             sc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
         }else{
             Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"SC : null.");
         }*/

         httpTransportSE.debug = true;
         //httpTransportSE.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
         httpTransportSE.call(mSOAPACTION, envelope);
         Object response = envelope.getResponse();
         tv.setText(response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
             Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"requestDump : "+httpTransportSE.requestDump);
             Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"responseDump : "+httpTransportSE.responseDump);
        }
    }
}
```

**requestDump** :

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" 
            xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <read xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/" />
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

**responseDump** :

> The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

**Note** : I have updated the code because I have found that web-service is of Soap version 1.2.

Comment: Are you sure that the service is using SOAP 1.1?

Comment: have you tried viewing the output in soap debugger to make sure it is sending vaild soap messages ?    check the link for a list of soap tools if you arent using one already http://soapclient.com/SoapTools.html

Comment: **request dump** shows soap request (soap message) and **response dump** shows server response.

Comment: I have followed the ksoap example and I have given **SoapEnvelope.VER12** Can you suggest how to do request in SOAP 1.2, because I am connecting to SOAP 1.2 web-service. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry that was incorrect - I didn't noticed that you have already changed the example. So you get the same error if you use `VER12` as well as `VER11`? If you cant the HTTP request what content types do you see for both versions?

Comment: Yes, almost same result is there.                                                              Before: <read xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/" id="o0" c:root="1"/>                                                        After: <read xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/" />

Comment: But what is the content type (HTTP header) in both cases? Do you have working client (.NET) for the service? Can you compare what requests does it send?

Comment: Request:                                                              `code` POST /MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/localendpointservice.svc?wsdl HTTP/1.1 `code`                                                      Response:                                                             HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.  (text/html)
@ladislav I have used Wireshark to trace headers. I am using KSoap2 at android side to connect to this web-service

Comment: Why do you have `?wsdl` inside the url? Remove it! It is only for retrieving service description.

Answer (score 1):

I think that current problem is in the URL. URL of the service is not:

```
http://192.168.100.188/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/localendpointservice.svc?wsdl
```

That is URL to service description (WSDL file) which accepts only HTTP GET requests (all SOAP requests to WCF service are HTTP POST). Your request from comment shows that you are trying to POST request to this URL - it will always fail. The URL of the service is without `?wsdl` query string:

```
http://192.168.100.188/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/localendpointservice.svc
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not change the output. Output still remains same even after removing **?wsdl** Is there any problem in Axapta configuration? because I have tested this implementation with Sample Java Soap 1.2 Axis web-service and it is working fine.

Comment: In such case you should use some working client and compare the HTTP communication between working client and service and your client and service.

Comment: Such kind of client is implemented in Wingows 7 Mobile platform, but it uses **Business Connector** which is using completely different way to connect with **Axapta Web-services**. Business connector is not using this namespace, soap action, url, method name etc. specifications.

Comment: So you need to build simple java or .net client (it can be console application calling single method) for the service to validate its functionality.

Comment: That's what I am doing but could not found it working. Problem might be at server side as mentioned here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone)

Comment: Now Actual Problem came. NTLM authentication is not supported and implemented in Android OS till now.                         http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4962#c67   However it is must for IIS server to authenticate. Can you have any Idea to overcome this OS level issue?

Comment: Ntlm authentication is nonsense if you want interoperable service. You must turn it off and use other authentication mechanism.

Comment: Actually same IIS server is used for Axapta so turning off NTLM authentication is not secured way. Is there any other way to implement authentication which is supported on Android and on Axapta's normal enviornment like its business connector?