# What is the benefit of a REST web service?

Tags: wcf

Recently I had to write 10 lines of .NET code to call a REST web service. It was very routine and everyday sort of code, so wasn't an issue. However, that made me wonder, what benefit is there to a REST web service which requires writing a few methods to call, as opposed to something like a WCF web service which you just add a service reference to and have an "API feel" (i.e. classes/methods etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It also has the luxury of being made far more open. Anyone who can write  can create a link to hit a REST api. I can't think of anything which is more accessible.

Answer (score 2):

REST and SOAP both are great in different situations. I'm not sure what's the nature of the service you are trying to call and where the service sits, but **sometimes** people says to use **RESTful services over the internet**, **and use SOAP based one within the corporate.**

You mentioned  :

> WCF web service which you just add a service reference to and have an
>   "API feel"

Assuming you meant SOAP based service, what you said is just true for VS users. What if you are trying to access a service using Apple's XCode? look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone) and see how many lines of code needed to replace the `Stubs` VS generates for you in XCode.

Also **generally**  RESTful messages are more lightweight than SOAP messages (look at [this](http://geeknizer.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol/)), which makes them more efficient when the bandwidth is an issue (e.g. mobile phones).

So when considering all aspects of service you are using, you'll get a better understanding of why the have used REST or SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

REST using HTTP itself as the API; it's more of a style than anything else.  People who are familiar with HTTP will understand a well-designed service immediately.  There's no WSDL or SOAP or XML involved.

I think it's lighter.  It's certainly easier for clients, because they don't need a SOAP client.  A mere HTTP connection will do.

The benefit has more to do with clients than the developer.

Answer (score 1):

You were consuming the service using .Net which has the tooling to deal with the SOAP service. Suppose you were on a mobile device, in a browser, or on a mainframe. Then that SOAP service would be a fatter and possible very difficult to implement. REST is tied closely with HTTP and virtually all technology stacks support it so it's able to reach as many clients as possible. That's why for me when deciding between SOAP and REST I ask myself who will be consuming this. If it's just a handful of .Net or other sophisticated clients then SOAP might be OK, If I need the largest reach possible the REST is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Because REST is using HTTP the way it was designed, you can develop clients on pretty much any platform and any language. The same goes for implementing the server. It is thought that many websites are already RESTfull. You don't have to understand all the WS-* stuff to be able to get working with the API. You can use something like cURL to interact with REST services. With SOAP it is far more complicated.

REST also supports custom content types, so its possible to perform a GET on the same URL (say `http://example.com/customers`) and get back an XML, JSON, CSV or XLS response by simply changing a header. This depends on the service implementation of course.  Some add an extension to the URL like `http://example.com/customers.xml` or `http://example.com/customers.xls` to achieve the same effect.  But the bottom line is you can save the stream directly to disk and use it.  The same applies when you send information to the server. You can send it as XML, JSON, CSV, XLS in their raw format. SOAP limits how and in what format you transmit the data.

A decent RESTfull service is also navigable, meaning that a reference to another resource is simply a link that I can visit (similar to HTML). This is almost impossible with SOAP.

SOAP security can become a complex beast. With REST services, simple HTTP authentication may be sufficient, or you can use OAuth and Open ID 2.0.

With REST its possible to have smaller payloads. This is great for a mobile environments and overall performance of those applications.

If you are monetizing your API, you'll find that it is simpler to support and makes your API available to the most number of clients possible.  We sold a product based on SOAP services and due to the complexity thereof and lack of support (by some JAVA frameworks) for the way WCF implements SOAP, we found it to be rather painful to support.

That said, it is really up to the developers of the REST service to ensure it is truly open, lightweight, simple and easily consumable. The payload and URLs needs to be documented rather well.  WSDL does this for SOAP and helps a great deal towards reaching some of those goals.

Answer (score 0):

With soap data format is XML. Its payload size is more than Json by big margin. You can google for perf test comparison b/w Json and xml. Rest does not impose constraint on data format. All types of client can use rest with same ease. Whether it is .net client or JavaScript running in browser. You can call also soap service from JavaScript but it is tedious and ugly.
Last we all want to be part of herd :-)