# how to consume WCF in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wcf, ios5, wsdl

I am trying to consume the WCF "/www.xxxxx.net/xxxx.svc" through the objective c and I followed the steps from the following link 
[Consume WCF Web Service using Objective-C on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone/988884#988884),

I am getting the following error

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetMembers' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Kindly help me in this regard,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your WSDL or service contract and implementation with WCF configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It not clear whether you are copying the ObjectiveC code as-is or not. The issue may be that the code in the SO answer you reference hardcodes an *invalid* string that is the soap XML to be sent to the WCF service. If you copied the code as-is, you need to send soap XML that is valid for your service.

If you have captured soap XML for your WCF service and its not working then the issue is still an improperly formatted soap message. In either case, I would first capture the messages from a successful call to the WCF service to determine what the correct soap XML should look like and compare it with the soap XML you are creating to see where the problem lies.

If it is at all possible, think about adding a webHttpBinding to your WCF service so you can use simpler XML for your messages. Look at this [four part walkthrough](http://www.robbagby.com/rest/rest-in-wcf-part-i-rest-overview/) on the webHttpBinding to get an idea of what it would take.