# Update UILabel from online source of data

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilabel

What methods are there to update a `UILabel` using an external resource, such as an online database or website, and could anyone provide any links or tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

An online database will generally require a [webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone) call. To update the value from a website you will need to make a standard [HTTP](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) call.

[Restkit](http://restkit.org/) for calling Restful API's.

Comment: :), you can also get a json file from that webservice.

Comment: Yes Restkit supports JSON. It is up to dbramhall to configure/determine the output of the intended webservice/site.