# SVC webservice - objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf, svc

[I referred this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone) & found it very useful but when I started trying every possible of it I failed in getting the desired output.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<SOAP:Body>\n"
                         "<BindCategory xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "</SOAP:Body>\n"
                         "</SOAP:Envelope>\n"
                         ];

NSLog(@"soapMessage: \n%@",soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://assetwebservice.sudesi.in/Service/"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService/BindCategory" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I think I must be doing some minor mistake. I am getting following output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>404 (Page Not Found) Error - Ever feel like you're in the wrong place?</title>
<link href="http://p3nlhclust404.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net/SharedContent/404-etc-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body-404">
        <h1>
            <span>Ever feel you're in the wrong place</span>
        </h1>
        <div class="info-container">
            <div class="inner-border clear-fix">
                <h2 class="info-top">
                    404 (Page Not Found) Error
                </h2>
                <div class="site-owner-404">
                    <h3>If you're the <strong>site owner,</strong> one of two things happened:</h3>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            1) You entered an incorrect URL into your browser's address bar, or
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            2) You haven't uploaded content.
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>      
                <div class="site-visitor-404">
                    <h3>If you're a <strong>visitor</strong> and not sure what happened:</h3>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            1) You entered or copied the URL incorrectly or
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            2) The link you used to get here is faulty.
                        </li>
                        <li class="last">
                            (It's an excellent idea to let the link owner know.)
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help to understand what wrong I am doing?
Any help is greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: the second line in the soap message corrected.

```
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                 "<soap:Body>\n"
```

Also in the url string .svc extension was missing. I corrected it with the statement.
*http://assetwebservice.sudesi.in/service.svc*
See well the s from service.svc is lower case whereas in soapaction parameter it is upper case.

Below is the entire soap message with http header parameters.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                          "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<BindCategory xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "</BindCategory>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                         ];
NSLog(@"soapMessage: \n%@",soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://assetwebservice.sudesi.in/service.svc"];    
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService/BindCategory" forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

*One thing still confuse me is that even if it is a GET request it throws me "ERROR in Connection" `NSLog` & succeeds when I change it to POST*