# Passing parameter to WCF function using Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

Anybody please let me know how to pass parameter to WCF function using objective c?
1. I used C# to develop WCF.
2. WCF end point is as follows.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="iAppServ.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
      <!--Endpoint for SOAP-->
      <endpoint address="soapService" binding="basicHttpBinding"     contract="iAppServ.IService1"/>
      <!--Endpoint for REST-->
      <endpoint address="XMLService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior" contract="iAppServ.IService1"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="True" name="webHttpBinding">
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServBehave" >
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <!--Behavior for the REST endpoint for Help enability-->
      <behavior name="restPoxBehavior" >
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true"  />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

1. I would like to consume "SearchUserData" function by passing a searchtext.
2. WCF will return XML data.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you even search for related posts or topics?  [Consume WCF Web Service using Objective-C on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/988884/745969).

Comment: And many more here - [Calling WCF with objective c](https://www.google.com/search?source=ig&rlz=1G1ACGW_ENUS358&q=Calling+WCF+with+object+c&oq=Calling+WCF+with+object+c&gs_l=igoogle.3...1428793.1432218.0.1432464.25.22.0.2.1.0.206.2424.14j7j1.22.0...0.0...1ac.1.HMeJwc4MgXI#rlz=1G1ACGW_ENUS358&sclient=psy-ab&q=Calling+WCF+with+objective+c&oq=Calling+WCF+with+objective+c&gs_l=serp.3...111342.111624.0.111793.3.3.0.0.0.1.129.332.1j2.3.0.ckwqrh..0.0...1.1.9.psy-ab.Y7OtCrO6dyM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45368065,d.cGE&fp=d9b9f9a5509b56c8&biw=1366&bih=703)

Comment: Many thanks, Tim. I've already tried searching the contents from the links you mentioned here. Most of them are using web service instead of WCF. Some of them are using 'Get' method. I'm new to objective C. Could you please shed some light on this topic?

Comment: WCF **is** a web service - it's Microsoft's replacement for their legacy web services (.ASMX) and remoting.  A Get method sounds like REST (another type of web service).  I've never worked in Objective-C, so I can't really offer much other than the links I posted.  Sorry.

Comment: That's okay Tim. Your help is appreciated. Waiting for more comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code work fine.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SearchUserData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><SearchText>"];

soapMessage=[soapMessage stringByAppendingString:searchBar.text];
soapMessage=[soapMessage stringByAppendingString:@"</SearchText> </SearchUserData> "];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your server.svc/XMLService/SearchUserData"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-16" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/SearchUserData" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
// NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(theConnection) {
    NSError *WSerror;
    NSURLResponse *WSresponse;
    NSString *theXml;
    NSData *myData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&WSresponse error:&WSerror];
    theXml = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[myData bytes] length:[myData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",theXml);



}
else {

    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```