# AFNetworking JSON post using Objective C returns unsupported media type

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I am trying to access a Microsoft CRM Web Service and I am using AFNetworking to do that. The service is configured to handle JSON request and response.

But when I do a JSON post I am getting this error:

> "com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415)} "

What is the Mistake i have done on the code.

This is my code:

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept" ];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type" ];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": self.Username.text,
                                 @"password": self.Password.text};

    [manager POST:@"http://www.xxxxxx.com/xxxx.svc/xxxxx" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Why are you afraid posting the URL? 90% of the time someone pastes the URL in their browser and knows immediately what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for "status 415" finds this straight from the horses mouth:

"The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."

In other words, the server doesn't support application/json.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the server was expecting a SOAP XML request. This is the code which solved my issue:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Authenticate xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><userName>"];
soapMessage = [soapMessage stringByAppendingString:self.loginUsername.text];
soapMessage = [soapMessage stringByAppendingString:@"</userName>"];
soapMessage = [soapMessage stringByAppendingString:@"<password>"];
soapMessage = [soapMessage stringByAppendingString:self.loginPassword.text];
soapMessage = [soapMessage stringByAppendingString:@"</password></Authenticate>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx.svc/Authenticate"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"application/xml; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/xxxxxx/Authenticate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
// NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(theConnection) {
    NSError *WSerror;
    NSURLResponse *WSresponse;
    NSString *theXml;
    NSData *myData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&WSresponse error:&WSerror];
    theXml = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[myData bytes] length:[myData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Data : %@, %@",theXml, myData);    
}
else {

    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

This post helped me [Passing parameter to WCF function using Objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057814/passing-parameter-to-wcf-function-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking from the CRM but you could try this:

```
[request setValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```