# Upload image from iOS to WCF service with stream parameter

Tags: ios, .net, wcf, cocoa, xcode5

I need your help on this please !

I have created my WCF service that acccepts a stream "image" to save it.
so here is the declaration :

service.svc:

```
 public void FileUpload(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
        FileStream f = new FileStream("D:\\sample.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        f.Close();
        stream.Close();

    }
```

IService.cs:

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/FileUpload")]
    void FileUpload(Stream stream);
```

so in my iOS code, I want when I click on a button a code execute to send an image to my WCF service.
can you please provide me with an iOS code to do that for me, knowing that I work with xcode 5 and iOS 7.

I used several code but no chance.

thank you.

Comment: This might be helpful to know how to consume a WCF service from a Cocoa environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone. Now, I have no idea how you can convert an iOS image object to a .NET Stream object...

Comment: thanks, I will look in your link